# Add order data to custom template on Admin magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a `layout/template` and including it within the Orders View page.

Adding static info to the layout/template is no problem but when I include order data (e.g. getBillingAddres) I get the following message on a blank page:

**Order View**

"Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving."

here's my template:

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder(); ?>
<section class="admin__page-section order-view-account-information">
<div class="admin__page-section-title">
    <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Order Information') ?></span>
</div>
<div class="admin__page-section-content">
    <div class="admin__page-section-item order-information">
        <?php /* Custom Order Information */?>
           <address class="admin__page-section-item-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormattedAddress($_order->getBillingAddress()); ?></address>

        <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
            <span class="title">
            </span>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I had a syntax error/typo in the php code in my template file (in my case, a missing end tag for php block). Check your php error log, the issue should show up there if it's not in magento logs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id or name at two place that's why it is showing error.Try to solved out this confliction because magento already have data for that id or name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to xdebug, I was getting a "Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!" error however you can only see this when you inspect the source code of the empty page which is why it can be hard to debug.

So you can increase the nesting limit or disable xdebug to fix this.