# Add multiple select control to fieldset in form magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to add mutiple select in form. I have try this:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'shipping_method_no_free',
            'select',
            [
                'options' => ['1' => __('Shipping method no free 1'), '0' => __('Shipping method no free 2')],
                'name' => 'shipping_method_no_free[]',
                'label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
                'title' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
                'class' => 'main_acount',
                'multiple' => 'true'
            ]
        );
```

But it is render like normal select.

I have also try this:

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'shipping_method_no_free',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'options' => ['1' => __('Shipping method no free 1'), '0' => __('Shipping method no free 2')],
            'name' => 'shipping_method_no_free[]',
            'label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
            'title' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
            'class' => 'main_acount'
        ]
    );
```

It render as i multiple select, but there are no content in it.
[image]

I have also try this:

```
 $fieldset->addField(
        'shipping_method_no_free',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'values' => ['1' => __('Shipping method no free 1'), '0' => __('Shipping method no free 2')],
            'name' => 'shipping_method_no_free[]',
            'label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
            'title' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
            'class' => 'main_acount'
        ]
    );
```

But it is render the page incompletly.

[image]

Is anyone facing the problem like that ?

Please, help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last one is correct form.

```
 $fieldset->addField(
    'shipping_method_no_free',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'values' => ['1' => __('Shipping method no free 1'), '0' => __('Shipping method no free 2')],
        'name' => 'shipping_method_no_free[]',
        'label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
        'title' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
        'class' => 'main_acount'
    ]
);
```

But it didn't render correctly, because i assigned the wrong value for **values** property. Change code like the following and you will be good to go:

```
 $fieldset->addField(
        'shipping_method_no_free',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'shipping_method_no_free[]',
            'label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
            'title' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
            'class' => 'main_acount',
            'values' => [
                ['label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free 0'), 'value' => 0],
                ['label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free 1'), 'value' => 1],
                ['label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free 1'), 'value' => 2],
                ['label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free 1'), 'value' => 3]
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Comment: hello @tam, how to render the values dynamically? instead of giving mannually

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'shipping_method_no_free',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'values' => ['1' => __('Shipping method no free 1'), '0' => __('Shipping method no free 2')],
        'name' => 'shipping_method_no_free[]',
        'label' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
        'title' => __('Shipping Methods No Free'),
        'class' => 'main_acount'

    ]
);
```

Explain: If you're using multiselect, you should use `values` instead of `option`

Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6d47e72c57025a8dd2bea8fef196f8397233c9c8/app/code/Magento/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Instance/Edit/Tab/Main.php

Comment: I have tried that also, but the page is not render the right way. Click here to see the image:
 http://prntscr.com/g3pab3

Comment: Clear cache or static deploy don't help?

Comment: No, it is still not work

Comment: Check exception log, any result?

Comment: There are no exception thrown. It is just system.log messge

Comment: And it is not related to the error.

Comment: See if it can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/add-order-data-to-custom-template-on-admin-magento-2

Comment: Thank. but it is not helping